# mysterious boot problems

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, live-usb, smart

From a live DVD I grabbed the [boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9gd5VqSGGG/), but it's rather lengthy.

Since the system seems to work from the live DVD okay, the inference is that it's just a booting problem.  How do I **troubleshoot** this booting problem further?

I'm inclined to run some [diagnostics](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html) on the hard drive, but it seems fine:

[image: smart]

see also:

[how to pass specific parameters to GRUB?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1023393/45156)

Comment: The question I see is *"Is that reasonable?"*. The answer is "yes, that is reasonable."

Comment: @user535733 fair enough -- I updated the question.  What can I do to find the problem?

Comment: What specific is the boot issue? You have the advanced LVM logical volume management with full drive encryption. And it looks like you have UEFI Secure Boot on, but have booted live installer in BIOS boot mode. You need to always boot in UEFI mode and may be better off with UEFI secure boot off. What brand/model system? Some do require boot parameters or drivers, but proprietary drivers cannot be installed if Secure Boot is on.

Comment: You're suggesting to disable UEFI secure boot?  Currently the system doesn't boot -- although it used to.  It just hangs part way through the boot, after POST, and never at the same point in the sequence.