# use this software in an EFI session -- why?

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi, live-usb

Running boot [repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) gives:

> The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and
>   use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature.
>   For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit
>   (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is
>   set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

Booting in EFI I can do.  But why?  This system never booted in EFI before, it's always been in legacy mode.  Also, this is error message is while using a live install disk of Ubuntu.  (I installed boot repair through apt.)

in relation to:

[mysterious boot problems](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024550/45156)